# Numpy Subtraction Precision

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array, `x`, that is calculated from a complicated equation:

```
x = (QT-m_μ_Q*M_T)/(m*σ_Q*Σ_T)
print(x)
print(x[0], x[1], x[2])
print(1.0-x)
```

This prints:

```
[ 1.  1.  1.]
1.0 1.0 1.0
[ -2.22044605e-16   3.33066907e-16  -4.44089210e-16]
```

Notice that the last line prints out something small and very close to zero but is non-zero. My next step is to take the square root of each value, so it should not contain negative values.

Explicitly starting with an array containing ones:

```
y = np.array([1., 1., 1.])
print(y)
print(y[0], y[1], y[2])
print(1.0-y)
```

produces the correct result so I'm not sure what the difference is:

```
[ 1.  1.  1.]
1.0 1.0 1.0
[ 0.  0.  0.]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Classic FP-math (combined with hidden magic inside prints).

Comment: Try `print((x[0], x[1], x[2]))` - by putting them in a tuple, you force `repr` instead of `str`- `repr` of scalars always tries to print the full precision in numpy. Don't think is a duplicate - the problem here is that `str(f)` is hiding information

Answer (score 3):

In short the ones in `x` are not truely 1. That's because you operate (the formula you used) on inexact values (floats are inexact, see also [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)).

However the default precision doesn't show the difference. But when you subtract one you get what is generally known as catastrophic cancellation (see for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) or [Why is 'catastrophic cancellation' called so?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1920525/why-is-catastrophic-cancellation-called-so)).

For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array([1, 1.00000000000002, 1.000000000000002, 1.0000000000000002])
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])

>>> 1 - np.array([1, 1.00000000000002, 1.000000000000002, 1.0000000000000002])
array([  0.00000000e+00,  -1.99840144e-14,  -1.99840144e-15, -2.22044605e-16])
```

Generally there are two approaches to fix this:

- Use a formula that avoids catastrophic cancellation (may not be possible). However in your case you could try `sqrt((y-x)/y)` instead of `sqrt(1-x/y)` - just insert the correct expressions for `x` (`QT-m_μ_Q*M_T`) and `y` (`m*σ_Q*Σ_T`). Mathematically both are equivalent but due to the floating point math these *may* give different results.
- Round your results and/or set negative values to zero.